# How to create shared durable mailbox for remote actors in Akka?

Tags: java, scala, redis, akka

I am working on an application which requires me to use shared durable mailbox for remote actors.

I was wondering if I would create something like a Redis-based durable mailbox with a single instance of Redis cluster and have all remote actors launched independently.

I'm not sure, however, how exactly durable mailboxes work. If I leave the name of the actors same and launch independent remote applications configuring them to use the same instance of Redis cluster would they share the mailbox automatically?

Is there a way to make do this? The mode ideal way would be to launch independent applications without other applications letting know about other instances. Still, it's not an absolute requirement.

Comment: Check out Akka's MapDB implementation at https://github.com/odd/akkax-scheduling/blob/master/src/main/scala/akkax/scheduling/mapdb/scheduling.mapdb.scala Mailboxes define basically enqueue and dequeue methods which are pull-style. So you need to persist and offer messages. Akka does not require messages to be serializable, so keep that in mind.